# есть ли способ прочитать большой json файл частями? golang

Tags: json, golang

Нужно прочитать большой json файл. Если читать вот так:

```
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    res := make([]Product, 0, 100)
    err = json.Unmarshal(data, &res)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
```

то в памяти придется хранить очень большое количество объектов, я хочу считывать каждый объект по отдельности и обрабатывать значения из него, после чего считывать следующий, что-то вроде такого:

```
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        fileNotEmpty = true
        line := scanner.Bytes()
        product := Product{}
        err := json.Unmarshal(line, &product)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalln(err)
        }
        // тут обработка значений
    }
```

таким образом память будет тратиться на один объект. Мой пример не работает, потому что во первых json хранит в себе массив объектов, из-за квадратных скобок и запятых десериализовать в одну структуру нельзя, во вторых он записан либо в одной строке, либо разбит на строки по полям, в обоих вариантах построчное считывание не даст информацию об одном объекте.

Есть ли какой-то способ обработать объекты json-a по частям, без считывания всего файла целиком?

Comment: OK google, golang json streaming parser не работает?

Comment: то что нужно, спасибо